# Display all hidden chat members in Gtalk

Tags: gmail, google, chat

Gtalk doesn't provide groups in chat window. If I am online, I am online for all. If I am invisible, I am invisible for all. So, I see a very large list when I get online. For me, say for example, few people are important to me right now. So, to hide other people, I set `Never Show` option to other people to whom I don't want to chat with right now.

- Assume I set never show for 25 people & now I don't remember all of them.
- How to `unhide` or `auto` to all of them back?

Please add comment, if you don't understand what I am asking for.

Comment: I totally get what you mean.. and I also was looking for that.. :)

Answer (score 1):

No answer here in a long time so I will try.

No, there is no way to bulk *unhide* the contacts that you said "never show."

However, Google Chat now provides a way to change the size of the widget on the left side of the inbox.

**Click on your picture** at the top of the chat widget. Under *Show in chat list* there are options to control how many contacts appear in your window. This should help prioritize the folks you chat with, allowing you to leave everyone as "Auto"

Answer (score 1):

Click on your picture at the top of the chat widget and drag. Then the option *Hidden contact* appears. The hidden contacts will be visible. Then click *Unhide*.